# How many of these contain an even number of A’s?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have some problem wrapping my head around the second question here.
They are actually set up to be one question. So I figured out the fist one..

How many size 9 words can you make out of the alphabet A,Z,Q ?

```
while using the rule of product, we can set up this problem like this:
```

`3^9 = 19683 Im i right ?`

```
How many of these contain an even number of A’s?
```

But this problem i have no idea how to solve.
can someone please explain how to solve such problem ?

Comment: Just to be sure, i assume you count $0$ to be even?

Comment: @Alistair: That should never be a question: $0$ simply *is* even.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. I agree that should never be a question. But unfortunately it is.

Comment: @Alistair: Not in connection with a problem from a book or an even minimally competent instructor. In my experience t’s a question only for the occasional student.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Again, i agree. But note that you didn't experience all the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is indeed correct. There are nicer approaches, but you can apply straightforward brute force to the second question.

- How many $9$-letter words are there with $0$ A’s? You already know how to answer this.
- How many $9$ letter words are there with $2$ A’s? To answer this, you must first determine how many different ways there are to place the $2$ A’s within the word, and then see how many ways there are to fill the remaining $7$ slots with Z’s and Q’s. You’ll want a binomial coefficient for this.
- Then answer the same question for $4,6$, and $8$ A’s, using the same ideas, and sum the results.

Comment: Okay, just to get a clear picture her.
-To determine how many different ways there are to place the 2 A’s within the word. Can be calculated like this **C(9,2)**, we have a word of length 9 and want to see how many ways there are to pace 2 A`s in it. 

-Then how many ways there are to fill the remaining 7 slots with Z’s and Q’s. We have 7 slots and 2 words. Isn't this then **2^7** ?

Comment: @user2968746: That’s right: there are $\binom92\cdot2^7$ words with exactly $2$ A’s.

Comment: But then i need to do this with 4, 6, and 8 A`s right ?
 **C(9 2)*2^7 + C(9 4)*2^5 + C(9 6)*2^3 + C(9 8)*2^1**

-The answer should be 9842.

Comment: @user2968746: I didn’t check the arithmetic for the final number, but the setup is right.

Comment: I am getting 9330

Comment: I found out that also 0(zero) is part of the even number situation. So after adding the C(9 0)*2^9 it gives me the value 9842.

Comment: @user2968746: Ah; I thought that you’d already done the $0$ part and were just working out what needed to be added to it. Yes, once you include the $0$ case you’re fine, and I’ve checked the actual computation now as well.

Comment: Thank you vary much for you`r help Scott.

Comment: @user2968746: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E_n$ be the number of $n$-letter words with an even number of $A$s, and $O_n$ the number with an odd number of $A$s.
$E_1=2,O_1=1$
To get $n+1$ letters, you either add an $A$ which switches parity, or else Q or Z which doesn't.  So $E_{n+1}=2E_n+O_n$, and $O_{n+1}=2O_n+E_n$.  It doesn't take too long to find $E_9$.
It might help to note that $E_{n+1}-O_{n+1}=2E_n+O_n-(2O_n+E_n)=E_n-O_n$, and $E_n+O_n=3^n$